# Plotting Callbacks in Keras

Tags: python, testing, keras, callback

Similar to how training and validation accuracy are plotted in Keras by storing them in history, I would also like to plot test accuracy over the epochs. I have used a callback defined to track test accuracy from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2548.

My code is

```
history = my_new_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 20, validation_split = 0.1, callbacks=[TestCallback((X_test, y_test))])
```

Now, I can only plot training and validation accuracy

. [image]Getting a KeyError for test accuracy.

**Can someone please help understand if the test accuracy can be plotted using the callbacks?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We calculate Validation accuracy after every epoch not test accuracy. If you are asking about plotting validation accuracy you could use `val_accuracy` as a key. Just use `val` as a prefix for validation metrics.

And also `val_acc` was renamed to `val_accuracy` from keras + tensorflow 2.0

Comment: Thanks. This is a separate callback for computing test accuracy over the epochs and hence the 'acc' metric. I am just monitoring the test accuracy.